# ROS1 to ROS2 in Burger

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, raspberry-pi, ros2

I want to work in ROS2 on my turtlebot3-burger (pi4), while I already work on ROS1-melodic. Can I do that with keeping my progress and without problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can start working with ROS 2 in parallel with your ROS 1 system. And you can bridge between your ROS 1 systems and your ROS 2 system using the ROS 2 bridge.

https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge

The transition from ROS 1 to ROS 2 will take some work and efforts. There's a [migration guide](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/The-ROS2-Project/Contributing/Migration-Guide.html) in the core documentation. Eventually you'll want to convert your whole system.

As a note ROS Melodic is now EOL which means that you may want to migrate to ROS Noetic first.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to port your own ROS 1 code to ROS 2 (slightly different approach to nodes and the like, but should go without too much trouble).

For the Turtlebot3 - ROBOTIS has a release TurtleBot3 2.1.5 with ROS2 Humble Hawksbill supported, [here](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/releases/tag/2.1.5).

More details about your project will help.

I've been working on upgrading TurtleBot2 from ROS 1 Kinetic to ROS 2 Humble, it's taken a while, but it's finally done.